# Clear reference implementations of MLAA?

Tags: graphics

Does anyone know of a clearly written reference implementation of morphological antialiasing (MLAA)?

Intel provide a paper and reference implementation at the following address, but I find the code very opaque.

http://visual-computing.intel-research.net/publications/publications.htm

Comment: Though this is a topic which can be applied in game development, I feel this question would be better suited at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's clearer than the original paper, but there is another implementation of the technique (or a variation on it) which I spotted in this year's Siggraph material.

http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~biri/mlaa-gpu/

As to whether or not you'd get a better answer over at the main site, I don't know - I'd say the majority of people interested in this technique are probably game devs...

Answer (score 1):

These guys have been promising to put some code up for a bit.  So this doesn't quite answer your question, but it might be something worth tuning into later.

http://www.iryokufx.com/mlaa/